# Parse server live query protectedFields.forEach is not a function

Tags: parsing, parse-server, livequery

i have an issue by using live query from parse server, it successfully connect to live server but whenever it received some message it show this error

```
error: Failed running afterLiveQueryEvent on class Chat for event create with session undefined with:
 Error: {"message":"protectedFields.forEach is not a function","code":141}
info: Client disconnect: 97a20d27-6c16-4ccf-9dd0-02ee89c3ab72
```

My issue solved without error